# Angular not routing properly. URL is localhost:8081/#!/#pageName

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, routes, view

I am making a simple Angular application that has an index.html which loads other HTML pages as views based on which navbar item selected; however, the routing is not working as expected. The main.html view is loaded fine, but none of the other views are loaded, and the URL is not what I expect.

The URL that shows up in the browser after an item is selected is `localhost:8081/#!/#pageName`. I do not know where the '!' is coming from, and there should not be a hash before the pageName. The URL that I am expecting is `localhost:8081/#/pageName`

app.js:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('videoGamesApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {                                                            
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/rankedLists', {
            templateUrl: 'views/rankedLists.html',
            controller: 'RankedListsCtrl'
        })
        .when('/addGame', {
            templateUrl: 'views/addGame.html',
            controller: 'AddGameCtrl'
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
            controller: 'ContactCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'THIS IS THE MAIN PAGE';
});
app.controller('RankedListsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'THIS IS THE RANKED LISTS PAGE';
});
app.controller('AddGameCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'THIS IS THE ADD GAME PAGE';
});
app.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'THIS IS THE CONTACT PAGE';
});
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>                                                                                  
<html ng-app="videoGamesApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">GAMING </a>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#rankedLists"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Ranked Lists</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#addGame"><i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i> Add a Game</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
                    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="sr    ch-term">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </nav>  
    </header>

    <div id="main"> 
        <div ng-view=""></div>  
    </div>    

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why are the other views not loading? Where is the exclamation point coming from in the URL? Why is there a hash before the pageName (I expect one hash, not two).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why are the other views not loading?** 
The reason why your views are not loaded is because you hit the route. You use 1.6 angular and expect the behaviour from 1.5. There has been a change in location hash-prefix:

> Due to aa077e8, the default hash-prefix used for $location hash-bang
>   URLs has changed from the empty string ('') to the bang ('!'). If your
>   application does not use HTML5 mode or is being run on browsers that
>   do not support HTML5 mode, and you have not specified your own
>   hash-prefix then client side URLs will now contain a ! prefix. For
>   example, rather than mydomain.com/#/a/b/c the URL will become
>   mydomain.com/#!/a/b/c.
>
> If you actually want to have no hash-prefix, then you can restore the
>   previous behavior by adding a configuration block to you application:
>
> appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
>   $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); }]); [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8)

**What to do?** 
**1. Set HTML5mode true**

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and in html set base in html header:

```
<base href="/">
```

Lastly change `<a ng-href="#pagename">` to

```
<a ng-href="pagename">
```

**2. Go back to old behaviour from 1.5 - set hash prefix manually**
This will make your app work as you expect in your question.

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

**Why is there a hash before the pageName?** 
The way you link is treated as a hashtag anchor tag. Which will scroll down to the current div with the given id. If you fix your problem with one of the above reasons this will be fixed aswell.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! Got it working by using your first suggestion.