# AngularJs routing not working when clicked on an anchor tag button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ijshMXmqTSlXcWIuuJjC) and added a simple routing. But for some reason routing is not working. I want to redirect to #/delete when clicked on a delete button, but nothing is happening.

**script.js:**

```
var appRoot = angular.module('myNgApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

appRoot.config([
    '$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', { templateUrl: 'ngIndex.html', controller: 'IndexCtrl' })
            .when('/delete', { templateUrl: 'delete.html', controller: 'DeleteCtrl' })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }
]);
```

**ngIndex.html:**

```
<a class="btn btn-danger"  href="#/delete">Delete</a>
```

Comment: I have seen your code just now ,your trying to open dialog modal through routing ,am i right? if its we cant do through routing for opening dialog modal ,For routing see this link http://embed.plnkr.co/kHXK54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it because of a change in angular 1.6 route with the hash-prefix. So instead og "" the hashprefix is now "!"

> Due to aa077e8, the default hash-prefix used for $location hash-bang
>   URLs has changed from the empty string ('') to the bang ('!'). If your
>   application does not use HTML5 mode or is being run on browsers that
>   do not support HTML5 mode, and you have not specified your own
>   hash-prefix then client side URLs will now contain a ! prefix. For
>   example, rather than mydomain.com/#/a/b/c the URL will become
>   mydomain.com/#!/a/b/c.
>
> If you actually want to have no hash-prefix, then you can restore the
>   previous behavior by adding a configuration block to you application:
>
> appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
>   $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); }]); [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8)

I made a similar post with possible solutions: 
[Angular not routing properly. URL is localhost:8081/#!/#pageName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665882/angular-not-routing-properly-url-is-localhost8081-pagename/41666300#41666300)

**From the other post:**

**What to do?** 
**1. Set HTML5mode true**

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and in html set base in html header:

```
<base href="/">
```

Lastly change `<a ng-href="#pagename">` to

```
<a ng-href="pagename">
```

**2. Go back to old behaviour from 1.5 - set hash prefix manually**
This will make your app work as you expect in your question.

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

**In your example** 
To see that this is the problem you can change

```
$window.location.href = '#/delete';
```

to

```
$window.location.href = '#!/delete';
```